# bundling facenet_pytorch using pyinstaller in virtual environment gives file not found error

Tags: pytorch, pyinstaller

I am trying to bundle my script via pyinstaller that uses these python modules

```
import base64

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

import os

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import torch
```

but when I run the executable build after bundling with pyinstaller it gives me this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/4_/xp6410q54xn78hfvvbd7v5lw0000gn/T/_MEIVyuj8j/facenet_pytorch/models/../data/pnet.pt`
```

I am building it using virtual environment with python 3.10.

So i have tried including modules in pyinstaller using hidden imports using this command and flags

```
 pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import="numpy" --hidden-import="torch" --hidden-import="facenet_pytorch" face_api.py
```

but for some reason it isn't able to package modules imported correctly. I wonder if any of these warnings is the issue.
I have also chekced site packages which indeed has the weight file in it's directory when installed with `pip insall facenet_pytorch`.

```
8959 WARNING: Cannot find path ./libtorch.dylib (needed by /Users/abhinandansharma/Desktop/face_api/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/_C.so)
8959 WARNING: Cannot find path ./libtorch_python.dylib (needed by /Users/abhinandansharma/Desktop/face_api/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/_C.so)
8959 WARNING: Cannot find path ./libtorch_cpu.dylib (needed by /Users/abhinandansharma/Desktop/face_api/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/_C.so)
8959 WARNING: Cannot find path ./libc10.dylib (needed by /Users/abhinandansharma/Desktop/face_api/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/_C.so)
```

When I tried the below command the warnings were gone but it still gave me error.

```
pyinstaller --paths "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages" --hidden-import="torch" --hidden-import="facenet_pytorch" --hidden-import="numpy" face_api.py



 Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "face_api.py", line 21, in <module>
          File "facenet_pytorch/models/mtcnn.py", line 214, in __init__
          File "facenet_pytorch/models/mtcnn.py", line 34, in __init__
          File "torch/serialization.py", line 771, in load
          File "torch/serialization.py", line 270, in _open_file_like
          File "torch/serialization.py", line 251, in __init__
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/abhinandansharma/Desktop/face_api/dist/face_api/facenet_pytorch/models/../data/pnet.pt'
        [37511] Failed to execute script 'face_api' due to unhandled exception!
```

Kindly help with this so that I can create an executable form my script.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after loading my standalone executable that I converted with PyInstaller and this was how I solved the problem. I solved it by editing the 'yourfilename.spec' file, generated by PyInstaller.

When you convert your script with PyInstaller, it will generate a SPEC file in the same directory as your Python file. The SPEC file will be named 'yourfilename.spec'. Open this file and add the full directory folder of your facenet_pytorch in your virtual enviroment to the 'datas list' in the SPEC file. See an example below:

datas=[('C:\...\...\...\...\Lib\site-packages\facenet_pytorch\', 'facenet_pytorch'),

The ... should be the name of some directory folders as indicated in your virtual environment. After doing this, re-run the PyInstaller using the SPEC file to regenerate the executable (use 'pyinstaller yourfilename.spec'). Then load the new executable and this should work as it works for me.

I hope this helps. Let me know.